# How to get bold and italic text in asciidoc mathjax equation?

Tags: formatting, mathjax, asciidoc

None of the following approaches produces output that is both ***bold and italic***:

```
:stem: latexmath

[latexmath]
++++        

\it{\bf{foo}}
\textit{\textbf{foo}}
\mathit{\mathbf{foo}} 

++++
```

=> How can I achieve ***foo***?

I use Chrome 67.0.3396.99 with the Asciidoctor.js Preview Plugin to render my the asciidoc file.

Related:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text
- https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/735

Comment: The relevant MathJax issue is https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/929, including  post to a custom macro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\pmb{foo}
```

(Some further chars to get to the 30 char limit for answers.)